# How to select a specific record from the table using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to insert data in a database. Here is the table in my application http://prikachi.com/images/681/6555681G.jpg. What I want to do is when I click "Edit" to select the concrete record and to have the option to edit or update it the way it is done here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/363040/updatedelete.jpg. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, C#.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var db1 = new beeContext())
        {
            var Article = new Articles1()
            {
                Author = TextBox1.Text,
                Title=TextBox2.Text,
                Text=TextBox3.Text,
                Category=TextBox4.Text
            };

            db1.Articles1.Add(Article);
            db1.SaveChanges();
        }


        Label5.Visible = true;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


}
```

ASP.net
I can't post a screenshot of the tables but there is nothing special - they don't even have relationships between - the whole application is just about filling the database.

Comment: asp? silverlight? post some code

Comment: Show some code, like your entity and DbContext

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify the entity retrieved from the dbContext and then call dbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: I'm sorry I'm too new in entity framework. Could you explain in detail what you mean?